# Frame on a resizable Window should show Scrollbar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, scroll

My app has a resizable WPF window with a frame which shows different WPF pages. Most of the time the pages are bigger than the frame and if this is the case, the frame should display scrollbar(s). Unfortunately, it never shows any scrollbar.

Here is my code:

```
<Grid>
    <Frame Name="MainFrame"
           NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
           Width="Auto"
           Height="Auto"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
MainFrame.Navigate(new Page1());
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wrapping your `Frame` in a `ScrollViewer`:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Frame Name="MainFrame"
               NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
               Width="Auto"
               Height="Auto"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
               ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! Note that the important part is also to warp the `ScrollViewer` inside `Grid` tag. This is critical.. I tried first to warp it inside `StackPanel` and it did not worked

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I gave up and just set the Visibility to Visible.  If it did not need the scrollbar then no real harm done.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem,  nothing worked. So I’ve used a workaround to solve it by adding scrollviewer to the target page
and setting page size to frame size

```
<Page x:Class="PageInFrame" Height="1050" Width="555" > …
<ScrollViewer x:Name="svScroll" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Height="1050" Width="555">
    …..
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Set/Replace page Height and Width property to target/containing frame size (can be done runtime or design time)