# Adding a Scroll Bar to a Frame WPF

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, frame, scrollviewer

One of the pages I load into my frame is considerably larger than the frame itself.  I have tried the instructions found at [Frame on a resizable Window should show Scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469548/frame-on-a-resizable-window-should-show-scrollbar) and my resulting xaml looks like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
<Frame 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
    Content="" 
    Name="mainFrame" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" 
    Source="LoginPage.xaml"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Unfortunately, when I run this WPF application, the pages and/or frame are completely hidden.  Removing the 2 ScrollViewer tags at the top and bottom of the code allow me to navigate again, but the problem page still has no scroll bars.

Answer (score 3):

My first guess would be you are losing the grid row you want to be in via the nesting.  Try this:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" >
<Frame 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
    Content="" 
    Name="mainFrame" 
    NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" 
    Source="LoginPage.xaml"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```